# How to Double Score the point for a word?

Tags: android

I have my first Android app and I am having difficulty on how can I double the point for a word/words whenever a player click an imageview. Basically, I want it to function like this: If the player hasn't click the imageview, the pointing system stays the same. If the player clicks the imageview the a message will pop-out (a toast perhaps telling the player that the points for the next 3 words will be doubled). How can I make this happen? How can I double the points for the 3 consecutive words without exceeding?

Here's my code for searching and calculation

```
//CALCULATE SCORE
private int optionTxtView = 0  ; //which textview to use for addition purposes
private int addClick = 0  ; //No. of clicks for search for calculation

private void calculate(){
    x = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
    z = x + y;
    score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
    }


//SEARCH WORD, DISPLAYING SCORE
public void viewWord(View view)
{   
    String s1= search.getText().toString(); //What word to search
    String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1); // If in db, display equivalent score

    if(optionTxtView == 0){
    //display the score on textview1
        tv2.setText(s2);
        optionTxtView = 1;
        }
    else{
        if(optionTxtView == 1){
    //display the score on textview2    
        tv3.setText(s2);
        optionTxtView = 0;
        }
    }

    //Display search word/s
    adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(addClick ==0){
        calculate();
        addClick = 1;
        text.setText("");
        generatedString="";
    }
    else{
        if(addClick == 1){
            calculate();
            addClick = 2;
            text.setText("");
            generatedString="";
        }}
```

Comment: you may need to provide more details about your code. Please add some comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean sDouble = false
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   //@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // Show your Toast message
      // double = true;
   }        
});
```

and where you are running your game code check the value of `sDouble`, if its `true` then double the scoring system inside a `for` loop, or set an integer value to `0` and increment it for next `3` words, after that set the value of `sDouble` back to `false`.

You may also need to make sure that the user doesn't click on the image for the next `3` tries after clicking it once.

**Update**:

Since your score is a `String`, you need to parse it to an `Integer` before performing any mathematical operation, use `Integer.parseInt(s2)`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand. Yes, I should have a boolean. But how can I make the score x2?The word and it's equivalent score is on my db. How can I make it double? e.g."ALPHABETH" has a score of 6 when the player clicks imageview, it should score 12.

Comment: which variable holds the score in your code ? your code seems so ugly. Is `s2` your score ? is it integer value ? Why have you stored it as a `String` ?

Comment: I have 3 textviews, the tv2(x), tv3(y) and score(z). the s2 holds the equivalent score. Sorry for the codes, this is my first app.

Comment: your `s2` is a `String` , parse it to an `Integer` value, multiply it by `2` and convert it back to `String`, if that is what you want.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(s2)` , then do whatever you want with your score on click of `imageView`

Comment: I tried to do it, but I don't know how to construct it right. :(

Comment: could you please add more details in your question about what have you tried ? and what is causing the issue yet.